# change height of a client window?

Tags: resize, window, client, awesome-wm

I was wondering if there was a way that I could resize window height in awesome. sort of like how I could make the master wider or narrower, is there a way to make a window lower in the stack taller or shorter? Documentation has not helped, so I figured I'd ask here before just giving up.

Comment: Are you talking about resizing a floating window or do you want to resize a tiled window? Since you mention "master", I suspect it is the latter.

Comment: its the tiled windows

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for window factors. The relevant API docs (that don't say much) are here:
https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html#awful.client.setwfact
https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html#awful.client.incwfact